# How can I use a custom Attribute within a DynamicProxy Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, attributes

I tried to assign a custom Attribute to class that comes from a dynamic proxy

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Login_A2947F53...
```

Example class Login

```
public partial class Login
{
    [CustomAttribute]
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now I try to access the Attribute using Generics and Reflection

```
public static void Process(TSource source)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in target.GetType().GetProperties(flags))
    {
        object[] attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(true); // <- empty
    } 
}
```

But there is no Attribute. Is that due to the DynmaicProxy or what did I do wrong here?

When I use a concrete class without dynamic proxy like this one, then I get the attributes.

```
public class TestObject
{
    [CustomAttribute]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [CustomAttribute]
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Something { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this one was obvious after a closer look;

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Login_A2947F53...
```

is a dynamicProxy type and know nothing about any Attributes. So I have to use the something like:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Login).GetProperties(flags))
```

instead of the dynamicProxy instance to get the type from. And finaly there are my Attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use **BaseType**.

```
public static void Process(TSource source)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in target.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties(flags))
    {
        object[] attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
    } 
}
```